# Is it normal for a pineapple to grow more crowns direcly from the fruit?

Tags: tropical

I've read about shoots/slips/ratoons/suckers (I can't keep track of what is what, and I think 2 of those refer to the same thing). I know one of them grows from the stem, below where the pineapple fruit grows.

But I haven't come across mentions of more crowns coming *from the fruit itself*

And bonus question: How do you remove the extra crowns growing between the leaves? I don't want to trim the leaves so I can't get a grip close enough to the base and I end up pulling out mostly leaves, and the poor base of the crown is left with almost no leaves, still attached.

Should I just trim the leaves in that area to get better access?

[image: growing from the fruit]

[image: after removal]